# How to check if a list of booleans contains a value?

Tags: haskell

How to check if a list of Booleans contains True?

eg

```
[True,False] = True
[False,False] = False
[False,False,True] = True
```

Comment: `or` should do that

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem

Comment: If the list is non-empty, you can use `maximum` ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always check for existence of standard functions in Hoogle.

For example: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BBool%5D+-%3E+Bool

Gives you several functions, out of which `or` is the one for this requirement.

EDIT:

`or` is a function. Its signature, `or :: [Bool] -> Bool` means it takes in a list of `Bool` and returns a `Bool`.

so, just doing

```
myList = [True, False, False]

if (or myList) then ..something.. else ..something else..
```

might be how you will use this in your code (replace ..something.. and ..something else.. with actual expressions).

Comment: How can I apply or to a list?

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `or` function:

```
> ghci

Prelude> or [True, False]
True
Prelude> or [False, False]
False
```

There's also the `and` function which returns `True` if all the elements of the list are `True`.

Answer (score 1):

The generic way to check if a list contains some value is to use [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aelem) as in

```
Prelude> True `elem` [True, False]
True
Prelude> True `elem` [False, False]
False
Prelude> True `elem` [False, False, True]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several funny ways to do that:

```
or
foldl (||) False
any id
not . all not
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) as search engines.
And surf [Platform libs](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/frames.html) for answer.

Reply is in the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html):

```
or :: [Bool] -> Bool
```